# Rviz not loading model

Tags: rviz, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS and was having a go at a tutorial for using the Clearthpath Husky simulator.

Gazebo works fine, but Rviz for the husky reports an error finding the model. I get this output in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 327, in <module>
    jsp = JointStatePublisher()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 25, in __init__
    robot = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(description).getElementsByTagName('robot')[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1931, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not None
```

I'm using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 13.04. Haven't been able to find a solution for this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151111/rviz-not-loading-model/) by [apple233](https://answers.ros.org/users/14651/apple233/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apple233](https://answers.ros.org/users/14651/apple233/) on 2014-04-10**:
Running rviz using the command roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
Are you using the right URDF model of the robot?. It seems that the joint state publisher has difficulty parsing the URDF file. Could you please post the launch file for working with rviz?. Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) with karma: 174 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apple233](https://answers.ros.org/users/14651/apple233/) on 2014-04-09**:
Hi,

I was just running this:
roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch

Which I believe is from ros-hydro-husky-desktop.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The view_robot.launch file is intended to be used with an existing instance of the robot in gazebo. So, to run this file first run: roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch. You can then launch view_robot.launch and select "Interact" to bring the interactive markers into view.

---

Originally posted by [ragtz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19335/ragtz/) with karma: 21 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2